# Two onClick events for Download options form

Tags: javascript, forms, events, onclick

I am trying to make a a form that will allow my to select a radio button that will change a button href location and open it in a javascript pop up. The JS for the href change that I have is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
// return the value of the radio button that is checked
// return an empty string if none are checked, or
// there are no radio buttons
function getCheckedValue(radioObj) {
if(!radioObj)
    return "";
var radioLength = radioObj.length;
if(radioLength == undefined)
    if(radioObj.checked)
        return radioObj.value;
    else
        return "";
for(var i = 0; i < radioLength; i++) {
    if(radioObj[i].checked) {
        return radioObj[i].value;
    }
}
return "";
}

// set the radio button with the given value as being checked
// do nothing if there are no radio buttons
// if the given value does not exist, all the radio buttons
// are reset to unchecked
function setCheckedValue(radioObj, newValue) {
if(!radioObj)
    return;
var radioLength = radioObj.length;
if(radioLength == undefined) {
    radioObj.checked = (radioObj.value == newValue.toString());
    return;
}
for(var i = 0; i < radioLength; i++) {
    radioObj[i].checked = false;
    if(radioObj[i].value == newValue.toString()) {
        radioObj[i].checked = true;
    }
}
}
//-->
</script>
```

The JS for the pop up is from Highslide JS (highslide.com)

the from code I have is:

```
 <form name="radioExampleForm" method="get" action="" onsubmit="return false;">
<p><label for="number0"><input type="radio" value="popups/download1.html" name="number"     id="number0"> Free</label>
&nbsp;<label for="number1"><input type="radio" value="popups/download2.html" name="number" id="number1">Premium</label>

<p>
<input type="button" onclick="return hs.htmlExpand(this, { objectType: 'iframe' } ); window.location.href = (getCheckedValue(document.forms['radioExampleForm'].elements['number']));" value="Download" class="button">
</form>
```

Is it possible to combine these, if so, what am I doing wrong? Both JS work just not when I combine them.

Comment: You are returning with the first event.  I'm not sure, but I think that's going to prevent the second from running.  Try wrapping both in a function with a single return value and calling that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Highslide allows you to override the iframe src via the `src` property of its configuration object:

```js
hs.htmlExpand(this, {
    objectType: 'iframe',
    src: 'mypage.html'
});
```

As Joshua pointed out in your current code: `return hs.htmlExpand ..` will prevent your second statement (`window.location ..`) from executing. Even if it was to execute, all it would do is change the location of the *current* browser window to the target URL.

A solution would look like this:

```html
<form name="radioExampleForm" method="get" action="" onsubmit="return false;">
    <p>
        <label for="number0"><input type="radio" value="popups/download1.html" name="number" id="number0"> Free</label>&nbsp;
        <label for="number1"><input type="radio" value="popups/download2.html" name="number" id="number1">Premium</label>
    <p>

    <input type="button" onclick="return hs.htmlExpand(this, { objectType: 'iframe', src: getCheckedValue(document.forms['radioExampleForm'].elements['number']) } );" value="Download" class="button">
</form>
```

Comment: That gave me a little more luck than what I was having, but now it is only going to download 1, no matter which radio button is selected.

Comment: I don't know what I did, but I have it working now. Thanks for your help!

Comment: You're welcome. I've created a jsfiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/MVKtj/) to demonstrate. Your console should be logging the correct URL.